# Не работает cv2.imshow вместе с waitkey

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(0,255,(200,200,3))
cv2.imwrite("save_image.png",a)
while True:
  cv2.imshow("window",a)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Изображение успешно сохраняется, но не получается создать окно, которое будет его показывать , если добавить print() после cv2.imshow, то принт не будет вызываться, в чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 0):

***main.py***

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(0, 255, (200, 200, 3))
cv2.imwrite("save_image.png", a)

# img = cv2.imread("D:\\PyCharm_PROJECTS\\New\\save_image.png")
img = cv2.imread("save_image.png")
cv2.imshow("image.png", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```